# Is there a way of detecting a hidden bug that only happens to specific person/hardware in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way of detecting a bug that only happens with a specific person/ hardware within a React application? Cause the bug is undetectable and never happens with tests and etc, only happens with a specific client from my company.

Any clue on how to debug those kind of hidden/undetectable bugs ?

Comment: what is the bug? what is the console output? is object related to that person missing some properties that you are doing some operation?

Comment: The bug is related to: there is a behavior that removes a particular key from an object that is being saved to database later, and also after some particular render, it maybe can change a value to its default.

Comment: Is this a bug within the development flow?

Comment: if you put debugger, it should throw an error, so you won't unnoticed it. again, without any code it's hard to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @GetCodeHelpatdialect.so it is happening within production but only for that specific user, so I can't/couldn't reproduce it neither my team mates

Comment: @wyvern800 can that specific user also reproduce the bug?

Comment: @GetCodeHelpatdialect.so Ofc, it happens all the time, but there's no error happening, should I try to debug with the client machine?

Comment: @wyvern800 if it's an error for an end user, could it potentially be a browser incompatibility issue? Are they not using Chrome for example, like Safari?

Comment: @GetCodeHelpatdialect.so maybe, that's what we are thinking at first, we'll see what is the problem tomorrow, thanks for the tips here, but I also was expecting for some kind of lib to help detect the issues within the user flow or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add something like https://sentry.io/ to capture errors in production, and get the stack trace of the error, and details like browser version, etc